# Send notification while in background to API greater than 26, using Notification Channels

Tags: android, xamarin, push-notification

I need some help please.

My app works to send push notifications in the background below API 26. These notifications show up in the notification drawer on Android. They work on an ANY API while in foreground, but above API 26, notifications do not get send in the background.

I understand that I must use notification channels for API 26 and above and I was following a tutorial, but I get an compile error at this point because
**noti_chan_urgent is not found.**

Also is this a good place to do the background notifications send for API > 26 ?

```
/

/ this service is used if the app is in the foreground and a message is received
        [Service]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
        public class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService
        {
            public const string URGENT_CHANNEL = "com.wj.sa.urgent";

            public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
            {
                base.OnMessageReceived(message);

                Console.WriteLine("Received: " + message);


                //get current build
                var currentBuild = Build.VERSION.Sdk;

                // check if API > 26 and do the background notification send if true
                if (Int32.Parse(currentBuild) >= 26)
                {
                    string chanName = GetString(Resource.String.noti_chan_urgent);     //error happens here
                    var importance = NotificationImportance.High;
                    NotificationChannel chan =
                       new NotificationChannel(URGENT_CHANNEL, chanName, importance);

                    // need to continue here  --- incomplete ---
                }

                try
                {
                    var msg = message.GetNotification().Body;

                    //pass message to xamarin forms, the picked up by main page and update the label if app is active
                    MessagingCenter.Send<object, string>(this, ShakeAlarmRR1.App.NotificationReceivedKey, msg);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error extracting message: " + ex);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You have to create a NAME for that Channel and you're using a Resource String that you have not added to the project. I'm not using Xamarin but your code seems coming from here: https://blog.xamarin.com/android-oreo-notification-channels/ and there it's explained all very good.

Comment: @emandt I managed to add the name of the channel in Resources/strings.xml so I am past that problem but still not getting a notification in the background. Suggestions plesae?

Comment: Follow the guide at the same link. It should help you in Xamarin development. I cannot help you with Xamarin. Try a simple project reserved/dedicated to only this target and test the code shown in the guide/tutorial.